# Entity Framework generated types not inheriting from EntityObject

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5

I'm new to Entity Framework (I'm using EF5), and I'm working on a test project to learn something about it.

Now I'm implementing some DAO classes to access DB following [this tutorial](http://cgeers.com/2009/03/14/data-access-objects-with-the-entity-framework/) (it's a bit old...)

I generated entity classes using Entity Data Model tool, but now I need all entities to inherit from EntityObject class.

Reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx) I expected it to be so, but actually my classes inherit only from `IObjectWithChangeTracker`, `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

So I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong...

Do I have to set some configuration in generation tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the correct template from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx - one of those that are called "EntityObject Generator".